# Fill a date field in mysql by the year, month, day, hour and minute from other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

i have a MySql table full of measurement data.

The measurement date in the table is stored in 5 separate columns: `year, month, day, hour, minute.`

What i would like to do is to add an extra column with the complete date, in a DateTime format.

So when i have the values

```
 year, month, day, hour, minute
  2013  ,1,    13,  17,    15,
```

there is a datetime field filled with the value `'2013-01-13 17:15:00'`

I'll add the column first, and after that i would like to execute a sql statement to fill the datetime field.

Can you help me with this sql statement?

(i don't know if it matters, but the statement should run from phpmyadmin)

Comment: Why on earth are you storing the date/time in individual fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE myTable set completeValue=CONCAT(year,"-",month,"-",day," ",hour,":",minute)
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard way of doing this would be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, '-') || COALESCE(field2, '-') || COALESCE(field3, '-') || COALESCE(field4, ':') || COALESCE(field5, ':') FROM table into table.field6
```

Comment: @njk: `||` can still be used for string concatenation in MySQL, if the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) SQL mode is enabled.